# wordpress привязка домена сайта к ip адресу сервера

Tags: wordpress, ip

Есть только админка wordpress сайта, можно ли домен этого сайта как-то привязать к ip адресу сервера? Если да, то что для этого нужно?

Comment: `домен этого сайта как-то привязать к ip адресу сервера` Что вы под этим понимаете? Домен в любом случае привязан к IP адресу, иначе по нему невозможно было бы подключиться к серверу.

Comment: Поменять ip, привязанный к данному сайту.

Answer (score 0):

Отображение домена на IP адрес может поменять только тот, кто вам этот домен выдал. В случае домена верхнего уровня (например `mydomain.com`) это регистратор, у которого куплен домен. IP адрес домена можно сменить в панели регистратора. В случае любого домена более низкого уровня - `mydomain.something.com` обращаться надо к владельцу домена верхнего уровня (то есть владельцу домена `something.com`), который изменит DNS запись для данного поддомена. Других вариантов нет, исправить DNS запись домена имеет право только владелец (или тот, кому владелец такое право делегировал, вариант кражи паролей не рассматриваем).